# Enums in java- sequence of variable declaration causing compile time error

Tags: java, enums

I created enum like:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6), VENUS(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6), EARTH(5.976e+24,
            6.37814e6), MARS(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6), JUPITER(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7), SATURN(
            5.688e+26, 6.0268e7), URANUS(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7), NEPTUNE(
            1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass; // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
```

but if i make variable declaration as 1st statement in enum,compiler won't accept it like

```
public enum Planet {

  private final double mass; // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    MERCURY(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6), VENUS(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6), EARTH(5.976e+24,
            6.37814e6), MARS(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6), JUPITER(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7), SATURN(
            5.688e+26, 6.0268e7), URANUS(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7), NEPTUNE(
            1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
```

Any idea why??  understand that probably this is what specification of enum says,but i am trying to understand it from compiler perspective that how sequence of variable declaration bothering compiler??

Answer (score 2):

thats just how the java syntax for enums is defined - the enum values are the 1st thing youre expected to write down, and only then instance fields methods etc.

see from the relevant part of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

```
EnumDeclaration:
    ClassModifiersopt enum Identifier Interfacesopt EnumBody

EnumBody:
    { EnumConstantsopt ,opt EnumBodyDeclarationsopt }

EnumConstants:
    EnumConstant
    EnumConstants , EnumConstant
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating an Enum, the enumeration values should always be the first to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

> understand that probably this is what specification of enum says,but i am trying to understand it from compiler perspective that how sequence of variable declaration bothering compiler?

No answer could entirely ignore the specification. Basically, the specification provides no flag for which statements the compiler should interpret as being the enum values. The language specification only allows for the use of the first statement as the indicator.